# Cannot start outlook web-addin in desktop without running as administrator

Tags: office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

A customer gets an error message after installing our add-in from Microsoft add-in store.

"Something went wrong and we couldn't start this add-in. Please try again later or contact your system administrator."

He gets the problem on all installed add-ins not only ours.

The system is Outlook on a desktop on remote desktop locked down by the hosting provider.
The support on the hosting provider gets the same error as the customer but when he runs outlook as administrator everything works as it should.

We cannot figure out what to check for next.

owa on web works fine for all this is only on the Outlook desktop.

Comment: Customer service questions are off topic here. For assistance on Microsoft Commercial Marketplace, Azure Marketplace, AppSource and Certification issues, please sign-in to Marketplace Publisher Support at https://aka.ms/marketplacepublishersupport 
 
• Create a ticket in Partner Center
• Browse Topics
• Category: Commercial Marketplace
• Topic: Offer or App listing issues
• Sub-Topic: Office Add-in
• Next step: Review solutions
• provide issue details

Comment: The problems as i stated is not about certification or marketplace its an outlook desktop thing with js add-ins.. 
Thought someone might now anything but as you said i will send a ticket somewhere else instead.

Comment: More information is needed here. What is the build version of Outlook? (something like 16.0.XXXX.YYYYY) What Version of Windows is this on as well?

Comment: Hi, its windows 10 and running the latest two versions of the O365 outlook client.
I'm waiting for teams meeting with the MS team. I will post solution here after we may have resolved it.

Comment: Sorry this is not fixed. 

Have been in contact with MS and everyone points to another so i have been going in the support circles for a couple of weeks now. 

The user is on a remote desktop on Windows Server 2016 Datacenter.
Running Outlook desktop Version 2013 (Build 13901.20400 Click to run).

Office add-in is installed and i can open it but the iframe immediatly gets the error.

"This add-in could not be started. Close this dialog to ignore the problem or click "Restart" to try again."

Office add-in works when user runs Outlook "as administrator" but not regular.